# Parsing Date String Using Moment.js Incorrectly Returns Unix Timestamp

Tags: javascript, html, momentjs

I'm attempting to parse a Javascript date from an html attribute using Moment.js.
I'm utilizing the `moment(String, String)` function to pass in a format string, but I'm getting what looks like a Unix timestamp returned. What am I missing here? Thanks!

```js
var from = $('#requested-from').attr('data-requested-from');
console.log('from: ' + from);

var requestedFrom = moment(from, 'MM-DD-YYYY');
console.log('requestedFrom: ' + requestedFrom);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.16.0/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="requested-from" class="hidden" data-requested-from=06-10-2017></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `format()` the moment however you like. MomentJS returns the timestamp as a default.

```js
var from = $('#requested-from').attr('data-requested-from');
console.log('from: ' + from);

var requestedFrom = moment(from, 'MM-DD-YYYY');
console.log('requestedFrom: ' + requestedFrom.format('MM-DD-YYYY'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.16.0/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="requested-from" class="hidden" data-requested-from=06-10-2017></span>
```